# Make AWS Load Balancer to choose specific instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-elb

I have AWS load balancing on REST requests between my services. One of my services has n instances and every instance is responsible for processing one type of data. I want to send data to specific instance responsible for processing that type of data. Is it possible to make load balancer to choose specific instance? My ideas was:

- use database to send request (instance will filter only own data type) and I think it is very bad design
- save somwhere docker address with data type and send request directly
- use brute force and send requests as many times as needed to get proper instance

I think all above ideas are very bad, maybe anyone has different ideas?

Comment: Yes, just put different instances in different Target Groups, and use ALB listener rules to define which requests go to which TG.

Comment: Load balance should have a routing logic, one option is having a URL prefix.
Using path base routing AWS ALB can direct user request to different target groups. You can create the target group with the application code you want.

for more details

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-achieve-path-based-routing-alb/